# Manipulate user's address bar with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, installation

I have a page at `example.com/themizer.php`, but I want it to appear that it's actually located at `example.com/themizer/` (or `example.com/themizer/index.php`) for all practical purposes.  I know how to basically make an alias for it with mod_rewrite, but how do I make it appear that users are being redirected to that alias?  Example: a user requests `example.com/themizer.php` and the address in their browser turns into `example.com/themizer/` *without actually redirecting*.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With server-sided configuration, you can only accomplish this with a redirect. This does not necessarily need to be a problem. Just make sure that the urls on your site point to the fancy url and not to the internal url. Otherwise you generate a lot of requests that have to be redirected, instead of just redirecting the odd request that came in in an other way (e.g. through an external old url or old bookmark). You do it like this:

```
#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /themizer\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^themizer\.php$ /themizer/ [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^themizer/?$ themizer.php [L]
```

---

If you really must, you can use javascript to 'push' a new window state into the history, updating the address bar. This causes the "go to previous page" button in your browser to contain bogus though. In other words: Going to the previous page does not work as expected, which I would not recommend since there is a better option available. You can do it with the following javascript statement in browsers that support it:

```
window.history.pushState( null, document.title, "/themizer" );
```